# Mysqli count not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli, count

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id),soft_name from table_name GROUP BY soft_name"; 
$d = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db_name, $sql));
$c = array_shift($d);
```

The result is always 2, but the database contains more than 3000 items. What could be the problem?

Comment: You have a `GROUP BY` but no `WHERE` clause, so it would be returning the `COUNT()` only for the first matched `soft_name` with one call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Instead of nesting `mysqli_query()` inside `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, which you should never do since it prohibits you from error checking, debug this with `var_dump($d)` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: var_dump($d) is array(1) { ["soft_name"]=> string(4) "1by1" }

Comment: That can't be, because your query is selecting two columns. It should have a key for `count(id)` but as you posted, it has only a key for `soft_name`. And to simplify access, you should give that an alias:  `SELECT count(id) AS count, soft_name...`

Comment: Yes, thank you. So I tried, but nothing changes.
print $d['count']; => NULL

Comment: Ensure you have PHP displaying warnings, because the results you are receiving do not reconcile at all with the posted code. At the top of your script (always when developing code) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  And I must assume that `$db_name` is actually a MySQLi connection resource, and not a string database name as its variable name suggests.

Comment: mysql error message no. Table and field names are correct.

Comment: please update your code whatever you are updated in  termaeklist.php

Answer (score 2):

Records are not pulled the way you are pulling for that you have to use similar to following code:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($db_name, $sql)){
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
         echo $d['count'];
    }
 }
```

More reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).